# No output from R presentation and ggplotly

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, iteration

I am trying to create an html presentation using R presentation.

I want to create iterative plots and that is why I am converting ggplot2 objects into iterative plots using ggplotly from plotly package. However, when I try to browse the presentation, instead of getting the iterative plot I get:

```
<!–html_preserve–> <!–/html_preserve–>
```

This is the code I am using:

````
test presentation
========================================================
author: 
date: 

First Slide
========================================================

For more details on authoring R presentations click the
**Help** button on the toolbar.

- Bullet 1
- Bullet 2
- Bullet 3

Slide With Code
========================================================

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

Slide With Plot
========================================================

```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
plot1 = ggplot(cars) +
  geom_line(aes(x=dist,y=speed))
library(plotly)
ggplotly(plot1)
```
````

Any suggestions/solutions to get the iterative plot?

Comment: Incorrect: you have a ploblem _without_ `r` ;-)

Comment: I see your ploblem, it's somewhere between `A & Z`. Idk why but I have a strong feeling it's an `R`

Comment: It might be due to the fact I am using windows10? I mean, are you able to get the interactive plot in the slide on your computer with the code provided above?

Comment: Marged, do you know where my problem come from?